# Ubuntu 21.04 can't connect to internet when it is emulated with bhyve on my FreeBSD 13

Tags: ubuntu, networking, freebsd, virtual-machine

I've configured the network stack of bhyve on FreeBSD 13 like u see below,but ubuntu VM can't connect to the internet.

```
1) on /etc/rc.conf : gateway_enable="YES"
    
2) root@marietto:/home/marietto # sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1 -> 1

3) root@marietto:/home/marietto # sysctl net.link.tap.up_on_open=1
net.link.tap.up_on_open: 1 -> 1
```

and then,on the konsole :

```
root@marietto:/home/marietto # kldload vmm

kldload: can't load vmm: module already loaded or in kernel

root@marietto:/home/marietto # ifconfig tap0 create up

root@marietto:/home/marietto # ifconfig bridge0 create up

root@marietto:/home/marietto # ifconfig bridge0 addm em0
ifconfig: BRDGADD em0: File exists

root@marietto:/home/marietto # ifconfig bridge0 addm tap0

root@marietto:/home/marietto/Desktop/Files/Bhyve/bhyve # ifconfig

em0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
options=4810099<RXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,VLAN_HWFILTER,NOMAP>
ether e0:d5:5e:e2:1f:22
inet 192.168.1.6 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
status: active
nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
groups: lo
nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>

bridge0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
ether 58:9c:fc:10:ff:b7
id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 hellotime 2 fwddelay 15
maxage 20 holdcnt 6 proto rstp maxaddr 2000 timeout 1200
root id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 ifcost 0 port 0
member: tap0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
       ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 128 path cost 2000000
member: em0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
       ifmaxaddr 0 port 1 priority 128 path cost 2000000
groups: bridge
nd6 options=9<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED>

vm-public: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
ether fe:40:5d:c8:de:75
id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 hellotime 2 fwddelay 15
maxage 20 holdcnt 6 proto rstp maxaddr 2000 timeout 1200
root id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 ifcost 0 port 0
groups: bridge vm-switch viid-4c918@
nd6 options=9<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED>

tap0: flags=8903<UP,BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
options=80000<LINKSTATE>
ether 58:9c:fc:10:ff:8e
groups: tap
media: Ethernet autoselect
status: no carrier
nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

And I launch the ubuntu 21.04 VM with the following command :

```
bhyve -c 4 -m 8G -w -H \
        -s 0,hostbridge \
        -s 4,virtio-blk,/mnt/da1p1/vms/os/ubuntu-budgie-gpu/ubuntu-2104-gpu.img \
        -s 5,virtio-net,tap0 \
        -s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5900,w=1440,h=900,wait \
        -s 30,xhci,tablet \
        -s 31,lpc -l com1,stdio \
        -l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI.fd \
        -s 6,hda,play=/dev/dsp8,rec=/dev/dsp8 \
        vm0
```

As you can see from the pictures that I have attached,the Ubuntu VM can't connect to the internet. Can you help me a little bit to understand why ? I'm sure that there is a problem with Ubuntu.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can your VM reach the gateway (192.168.1.1 from your configuration)?  Does the gateway properly route your VM to the internet?  If I am reading your output properly, it appears that the `bhyve` host is at 192.168.1.6, but how is the server at 192.168.1.1 configured?  You may need to check some output of `tcpdump` on the gateway to see if your packets are being received and routed properly.

Comment: no. it says : destination host unreachable. tcpdump gives this output : https://ibb.co/Y2fHYrC

Comment: I find it strange that you add em0 as a bridge port but leave the IP on it. Even if FreeBSD works fine with it, I would have moved the IP address from em0 to bridge0. man page bridge(4) tells you can do it. I think you should try it.

Comment: you say to do something like this ? ---> https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-duplicate-the-tap0-interface-in-a-new-tap1-network-interface-that-it-is-not-used.81671/post-527031 ; someone else suggested me to follow that method,but as u can see,it didn't work. I'm not sure that it can work. Infact if you see how the network interfaces on freebsd appears after that they have been properly configured by vm-bhyve,you will not see an IP address assigned to the bridge.

Comment: Having em0 getting back an IP address suggests that a DHCP client is still running on the wrong interface. Anyway, that was a suggestion, having no experience with FreeBSD, I can't do more.

Comment: @GracefulRestart : this is the tcpdump made on freebsd : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ghVdS56Y6f/ ; actually 1.7 is the IP assigned to ubuntu guest os : https://ibb.co/fkW04fx